# how to trace all assignments of specific class object in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-corruption

I got a memory corruption problem in my program.  I've figured out there is an class pointer wrote to an incorret place. I want to trace all assignment of this kind of objects, check them one by one.

There are probably half million lines in my codes. I can't do that manually.Are there any tools or compile options will help me?

Comment: Seen http://valgrind.org?

Comment: The "class pointer wrote to an incorret place" doesn't help much. But the " trace all assignment of this kind of objects" part could be done by overloading the operator= and copy-constructor of this class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what platform you're using. But most debuggers have the idea of a watch point, where you can watch specific variables.

For GDB you just type `watch foo` and run the code

See more here:

http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html

[How can I use "watch" GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835757/how-can-i-use-watch-gdb)

Alternatively, just use `valgrind` to find your memory corruption, it is very good at it.